# What is Valid Xpath for link extract by div class name?

Tags: xpath, web-scraping

What is Valid Xpath for link extract by div class name?

Here is html code:

```
<div class="poster">
<a href="/title/tt2091935/mediaviewer/rm4278707200?ref_=tt_ov_i"> <img alt="Mr. Right Poster" title="Mr. Right Poster" src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BOTcxNjUyOTMwOV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMzUxMDk4NzE@._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg" itemprop="image">
</a>    </div>
```

I want to know exact Xpath as if i found href link.
I try with //a/@href[@class='poster'] but it's doesn't work

Comment: The class is on the div, not the anchor.

Comment: Yea. I want link for <div class="poster">

Comment: Yes, which is why you'd use it as a criterion for `div`, not `a` or `@href`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<div>` contains the `<a>` so you can use that to navigate:

```
//div[@class='poster']/a/@href
```

Remember that the `"poster"` class is defined on the `<div>` not on the `<a>` so that's where you need to apply the predicate.

- `//div` returns all `<div>` elements
- `[@class='poster']` is a predicate that filters by class
- `/a` returns all `<a>` elements that are children of those `<div>`s
- `/@href` gives us the attribute we want

Depending on the system you're using you might need to wrap the whole expression in `text()` in order to bring back the attribute data rather than the DOM node.